# Laravel custom LoginController doesn't persist session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-8

My system is built using Vue and Laravel. My requirement is to send a one-time password to the User on each login. Hence, I have created a custom login API controller. I can create a Passport token and send it back to the User. However, I also want Laravel to persist the user session, but, that's not happening. Below is my code for reference:

**Api\LoginController.php**

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    if (auth()->attempt($data)) {
        $token = auth()->user()
            ->createToken(config('app.passport_token_key'))->accessToken;

        $user = User::whereEmail($data['email'])->first();

        // It is not persisting. When I redirect the user to the next page, 
        // it doesn't pass the auth middleware.
        auth()->login($user);

        if ($this->sendVerificationCode($user)) { // Send One Time Password
            return [
                'token' => $token,
            ];
        }
    }

    return ['error' => true, 'message' => 'Unauthorized'];
}
```

**web.php (route file)**

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class,
        'index'])->name('home');
});

Auth::routes();
```

**api.php (route file)**

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;

Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])
    ->name('api:login');
```

I am calling the login API using Vue JS (Axios).

Once the user is logged in (via API), my end goal is that `web`, and `api` both guards should know the user session. However, only the `api` guard can authenticate me (not the `web` guard).

Comment: Just don't use JS to perform API calls, but use PHP... besides your `api.php` has no middleware. I'd suggest to define a custom middleware for this task and assign it to both of them.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - Calling API is one of the things my VueJS code is doing. I tried the middleware idea too, however, I couldn't achieve it because of my main problem "saving/persisting the user session". Thanks

Comment: Creating the problem and then ignoring might not be helpful.

Comment: it seems no more than logic to me that the API auth and web auth don't mix... but i think that if you add the web middleware to the api routes it will work

Comment: @SarjitDelivala what's the reason behind using both web and API?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the `StartSession` middleware is only present in the web routes. Check your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file, it should be something like this:

```php
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            // NOTE the StartSession Here
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

If you want to use the session, you should add the middleware to your login route.
Inside the `$routeMiddleware` array inside `app/Http/Kernel.php` add:

```php
  'session.start' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

Then add the middleware to the logi route in your `routes/api.php` file:

```
Route::post('login', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\LoginController::class, 'login'])
   ->name('api:login')
   ->middleware('session.start');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this is not working. I tried logging in to the form and then navigate to Home Page but, 'auth' middleware is failing at /home route in web.php

Comment: You may need to add the `EncryptCookies` middleware aswell because the auth token is stored on an encrypted cookie